# Haskell expression data type

Tags: haskell, types

I want to have the following data type in Haskell :

```
data Exp = Add Exp Exp
     | Var String 
     | Let (Var String) Exp Exp
     | Int Int
```

However, using (Var String) like that is not allowed. I could use Exp instead of (Var String), but I don't want an Int to be allowed there, so how can I solve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can't understand what's your goal.

Comment: I want to create the data type Exp which contains Let (Var String) Exp Exp. However, I can't use (Var String) like that to restrict it, but I can't write Let Exp Exp Exp either as I don't want an integer in the first Exp.

Comment: Can you use just `String` instead of `(Var String)`? `Let String Exp Exp`

Comment: Ah, I see now. Just use `Let String Exp Exp`. Alternatively, if you want more wrapping, use `...| Var Var | Let Var Exp Exp | ...` and then define `newtype Var = V String` or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a newtype wrapper `Var` or just use `String`.  First the newtype wrapper example:

```
newtype Var = V String
-- ^ "Var" here is a type declaration. "V" is declaring a data constructor.

data Exp = Add Exp Exp
     | Var Var          -- The first "Var" here is declaring a data constructor. The second is referring to the type.
     | Let Var Exp Exp  -- "Var" here is referring to the type
     | Int Int
```

Or just with strings:

```
data Exp = Add Exp Exp
     | Var String 
     | Let String Exp Exp
     | Int Int
```

EDIT:  The point my comments were trying to make is probably unclear.  In your use of Var, such as `Let (Var String) Exp Exp`, you tried to use a constructor named `Var` (and it's field, `String`) in a location that requires a *type*.  Each data constructor can be used to build a *value* of the type (*Exp* in this case) and can not be further distinguished by the type system.  In lieu of an additional data declaration you can't distinguish between a value of type Exp that is a `Var` from one that is an `Add`, `Let`, or `Int`.